Error when creating docker image for spring boot jar file
My boot project consist of spring mvc and spring jpa using mysql.
When I run the .jar its running error free and normally as expected without any errors or issues.
but when I'm trying to create the Dockerfile & using docker run my_img_id where my Dockerfile is there,
my Spring Dockerfile below
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "java","-jar","/app/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]

My Application.properties file contents below.
spring.application.name=demo
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= admin

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.boot.allow_jdbc_metadata_access=false

server.port= 1001
#spring.devtools.restart.enabled= true
#spring.devtools.livereload.enabled= true
#spring.main.log-startup-info= false
#spring.devtools.restart.enabled= true
spring.main.lazy-initialization= true

I'm kind a unaware of docker-compose
2024-08-27T14:52:10.818Z  WARN 1 --- [demo] [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1431) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1502) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:32) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]

2024-08-27T14:52:10.830Z ERROR 1 --- [demo] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
2024-08-27T14:52:10.833Z  WARN 1 --- [demo] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
2024-08-27T14:52:10.845Z  INFO 1 --- [demo] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-08-27T14:52:10.882Z  INFO 1 --- [demo] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-08-27T14:52:10.906Z ERROR 1 --- [demo] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:32) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:221) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1431) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1502) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentWithDefaults(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        ... 35 common frames omitted


I check so may articles, old questions but nothing seems to worked for me.
Also someone suggested me to try adding jdk bin folder path too and when I tied that to in my Dockerfile the below path as
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin
COPY C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-21/bin /usr/local/bin/

Error,
 ERROR [4/6] COPY C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-21/bin /usr/local/bin/  

is there anything that I'm missing or any corrections that I can make?

Please edit your question with the entire stacktrace of the error. Based on your descriptions so far it is likely that your application running on the container is not able to connect to your Mysql running in your machine (host).

@JorgeCampos
As you mentioned I added the full Stack trace.

Try adding this to your application properties: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect don't forget to re-generate the jar before re-creating the container. Also make sure your Mysql is accessible from external.

Using that following line resolves the termination of docker run, but
since when since I changed the port from 8080 (since tomcat was opening) to 1000,
but img is not giving anything when I run as localhost:1000
and I sure that I mentioned some message for "" path

Also its seems to suppress the issue but issue is still there

So your configuration says server.port= 1001 and you are exposing 1000 why ?

ooh, so it should be 1001 only?
suppose if I didn't mentioned server port in app.props files, then can I define any port at docker?

Not any port, you need to expose the port your application is configured to run. Otherwise nothing will be able to reach it from external (your machine, the host). So if your docker EXPOSE need to match the configuration your application is set to run server.port= 1001 so, yes it needs to be 1001.

Another thing I noticed from your post is that you set the image as a jdk 17 openjdk:17-jdk-alpine and you don't need to copy any java files to it, the image already has a java in it less yet one of version 21 COPY C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-21/bin

oooh I think I focused on the issue that I forget to set it to see it,
by the way is copying the jdk/bin is mandatory to declare in dockerfile?

no no, that is exactly the point, that docker image you referenced on the first line: FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine is the base image of the operating system that will run in the container and that is already built with stuff in it for this particular case, open jdk 17, you can check here how the image is built: https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/openjdk/17-alpine/images/sha256-a996cdcc040704ec6badaf5fecf1e144c096e00231a29188596c784bcf858d05
